# Pass additional information, besides the batch and batch_idx, in the training step of pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

While training a model with PyTorch Lightning, I want to calculate a metric that depends on information additional to the batch. Is there a way to pass an argument additional to the batch and the batch index in the `training_step` method of a `LightningModule`?

I tried passing the information in the batch as an additional dictionary, but PyTorch Lightning concatenates the values in the dictionary with themselves, the same number of times as the *batch_size*. This works, but in the process a giant tensor is created unnecessarily and this does not scale to larger problems.

Another workaround is to directly add the information as an attribute of the model, so that the information is always available to calculate the metric I need, but I would prefer not to modify my model since the information is not necessarily available and I do not want to create an additional class just to "wrap" the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could build a custom Callback, see [the docs page](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/api/lightning.pytorch.callbacks.Callback.html#lightning.pytorch.callbacks.Callback).

Comment: I tried this but couldn't make it work. I also ended up giving up lightning altogether. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue where I trained a contrastive learning model and I want to get the output of that model and use it to train another model. I notice that Pytorch Lightning seems to fine-tune that encoder model when I train the second model. [Repo](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-not-use-model-eval-in-training-step-method-on-lightning/122425/4) says that by default `training_step` converts everything there to training mode.

So I initialised my model as global and then passed it to the training step. Like this,

```
global model
model = model.to('cuda')
encoder_out = model(normal_image)
```

`model` is loaded as `global` before the second model is defined and passed to the training step as a global model.

I hope that this might help you.